# Why when I test ``` repository.delete()``` we do not need imitate repository.delete()?

Tags: java, spring-boot, testing, mocking, mockmvc

I have the following code:

```kotlin
@DeleteMapping(value = ["/library/books/{id}"])
fun deleteBook( @PathVariable("id") id: kotlin.Int): ResponseEntity<Unit> {
    return ResponseEntity(service.deleteBook(id), HttpStatus.valueOf(200))
}

override fun deleteBook(id: Int) {
    libraryRepository.findById(id).let {
        if(it == null){
            throw NotFoundException("Book with the given id not found")
        }
        libraryRepository.delete(it)
    }
}

@Test
fun `delete book and return 200`(){
    val library = Library(name = "testName", author = "testAuthor")
    `when`(libraryRepository.findById(1)).thenReturn(library)
    mvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.delete("/library/books/1"))
            .andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.status().isOk)
    verify(libraryRepository).delete(library)
}
```

Here I am trying to write test, I suppose that it should fail, but it passed. I don't understand why my test is working, although I do not imitate `` when`(libraryRepository.delete(...)) ``.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at your function:

```kotlin
override fun deleteBook(id: Int) {
    libraryRepository.findById(id).let { //1
        if(it == null){
            throw NotFoundException("Book with the given id not found")
        }
        libraryRepository.delete(it) //2
    }
}
```

Since you wrote:

```kotlin
`when`(libraryRepository.findById(1)).thenReturn(library)
```

method `findById` will return library instance, and then that instance will be passed to `delete`() method of `libraryRepository`. Since you didn't specify what should happen when this method is invoked, this line:

```kotlin
libraryRepository.delete(it)
```

Will return `null`.

Finally, you wrote this line of code in your test:

```kotlin
verify(libraryRepository).delete(library)
```

And since `delete` method of `libraryRepository` has been invoked, your test will pass.

Comment: thank you for your answer, how I understood because of libraryRepository.delete(it) returns null, that's why i do not need imitiate with the following code `when`(libraryRepository.delete(...))? Is it right?

Comment: @Johny yes, if you don't specify what should method return when invoked on mock object,it will return null. You can check that in debugger

Comment: @Johny if this answer was helpful for you please mark it as accepted.